# const and STL containers

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

The following `std::vector` code is giving errors

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<const double> VectDouble;
    VectDouble.push_back(2.34);
    VectDouble.push_back(2.33);
    VectDouble.push_back(2.32);

    for(std::vector<const double> VectDouble::iterator i=VectDouble.begin();i!=VectDouble.end();++i)
       std::cout<<*i;

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Your STL container elements should be assignable and copy-constructible.

`const` prevents it from being [assignable](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Assignable.html). Remove `const` and try compiling your code again.

Also change `std::vector<double> VectDouble::iterator` to

`std::vector<double>::iterator`

Answer (score 2):

VectDouble is a variable name.

change

```
for(std::vector<const double> VectDouble::iterator i=VectDouble.begin();i!=VectDouble.end();++i)
```

to

```
for(std::vector<const double>::iterator i=VectDouble.begin();i!=VectDouble.end();++i)
```

or

```
typedef  std::vector<const double> vector_t;
for(vector_t::iterator i=VectDouble.begin();i!=VectDouble.end();++i)
```